# strrev() with binary numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to reverse a binary number using PHP, I'm trying to use `strrev();` but I didn't get correct number.

```
$binNumber = 0101;

echo strrev($binNumber);
```

Comment: `0101` is an octal integer literal.

Comment: I get the number 56-

Comment: @RubenLopez That's because your number isn't a binary number it's octal which is 65 and reversed it's 56

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: To make sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); why do you have to reverse a binary number? With `100010` (`34`) are you expecting `010001` (`17`) or `011101` (`29`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here i use it as a string reverse it and then print the binary number

```
$binNumber = "0101";
echo bindec(strrev($binNumber));
```

Output:

```
10
```

**FYI:**

Since PHP +5.4 you can use the prefix `0b` for binary numbers. (E.g. `echo $binNumber = 0b0101;` -> `5`)

Comment: @RubenLopez You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works!)